# Items in DataGrid not initialized as expected

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events

I seem to have a problem of items not being created as expected, resulting in event-listeners not being fired.

I am using a DataGrid column of checkboxes as seen here:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="gridComponents" height="100%">
    <mx:columns>
        <fwctrl:DataGridCheckBoxColumn id="colChkBox" width="20" selectionChanged="onGridChbBoxChange(event)" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Components" dataField="name" width="250"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

(*fwctrl* is the namespace of an internal library.)

And here is what the mxml of *fwctrl:DataGridCheckBoxColumn* looks like:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" resizable="false" xmlns:grid="fwctrl.grid.*" xmlns:CheckBoxColumn="fwctrl.grid.CheckBoxColumn.*">
<mx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="selectionChanged", type="fwctrl.grid.CheckBoxColumn.DataColumnCheckBoxEvent")]
</mx:Metadata>
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        ...

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:headerRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <CheckBoxColumn:CheckBoxHeaderRenderer textAlign="center" click="checkboxheaderrenderer1_clickHandler(event)">

            <mx:Script>
            ...
            </mx:Script>
        </CheckBoxColumn:CheckBoxHeaderRenderer>
    </mx:Component>
</mx:headerRenderer>
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:Box horizontalAlign="center"
                verticalAlign="middle" enabled="{outerDocument.isEnabled}">
            <mx:Script>
                <![CDATA[
                    ...         


                    protected function checkBox_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                    {
                        trace("init checkbox");
                    }

                ]]>
            </mx:Script>
            <mx:CheckBox id="checkBox" click="onCheckBoxClick()" change="onChange(event)" initialize="checkBox_initializeHandler(event)"/>
        </mx:Box>
    </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```

*CheckBoxHeaderRenderer* is a class that inherits from checkbox.

using the mxml above I bind an `ArrayCollection` to the data provide by doing: `gridComponents.dataProvider     = coll;`

Having the `checkBox_initializeHandler` event bound, I expect to see a message printed for each element in my collection.

In reality, the message will only be displayed for element that don't "fall off the grid", i.e. if there is a scroll bar (due to a lot of items being rendered), the items that are below the bottom of the grid (i.e. the ones that need to be scrolled to) will not print a message.

This also means that they are not created correctly and that the `click="onCheckBoxClick()"` is not hooked correctly and that `onCheckBoxClick()` does not get triggered.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Could you add more details on your dataProvider and your onCheckBoxClick() function?  I can offer better advice if you post those, too.

Answer (score 0):

In Flex, itemRenderers aren't created on a one-to-one basis with your underlying data collection.  You only get enough instances to display one screen's worth of data, and those instances get reused as you scroll.

To handle this in your code, refactor so that your `click` handler in the itemRenderer updates a property in your dataCollection (e.g. `data.foo = true;`).